# Problems to load .csv files generated in Social Network Benchmark to Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I've got problems in my work with Neo4j, and if you please to help, I will thank you a lot!

My work is something like this. I´ve got to study and evaluate several graph databases, and to do that I must use a benchmark. The benchmark that I'm used is the Social Network Benchmark (SNB)
I generate files with different setups all accordingly to the setup chosen. Something similar to this: forum_0.csv
This .csv files got certain headers, like this: `id | title | creationDate | etc...`
The next step in my project is to load them to Neo4j, build a database to test them with certain query’s, and my problems start here at this point.

I have loaded some files to Neo4j but others don't because of errors and I don't understand why.

I'm using this code to load those files. In this example I load the forum.csv to Neo4j.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM ".../forum_0.csv" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
CREATE (:FORUM_0 {id:csvLine.id, title:csvLine.title, creationDate:csvLine.creationDate})
```

And with this code, the data from this file is loaded to Neo4j correctly.

But with this file - forum_containerOf_post_0.csv I can´t load the data correctly with this header - `Forum.id | Post.id`.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM ".../forum_containerOf_post_0.csv" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
CREATE (:FCOP_0 {Forum.id:csvLine.Forum.id, Post.id:csvLine.Post.id})
```

The problem in here is I can´t access the id of forum_0.csv in the load process of forum_containerOf_post_0.csv. How can I access to that id, or another property? Is the lack of some Cypher code?
Is there something wrong in the process? Is there someone here that work with this - SNB and Neo4j?

Is there someone here to help me in this problem?

I tried to explain my problem but if you have questions about my problem, feel free to ask.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the headers in the second file.  If you want to embed periods `.` in the header column names you need to back tick the columns when you reference them in the load csv statement.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM ".../forum_containerOf_post_0.csv" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
CREATE (:FCOP_0 {Forum.id:csvLine.`Forum.id`, Post.id:csvLine.`Post.id`})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you got right in your answer, but with a little correction

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM ".../forum_containerOf_post_0.csv" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR "|"

CREATE (:FCOP_0 {`Forum.id`:csvLine.Forum.id, `Post.id`:csvLine.Post.id})
```

But I discover other problem. This creates me the FCOP_0 node label but without the properties that the forum_containerOf_post_0.csv have. The two properties are Forum.id and Post.id, but with this process the properties are not loaded to the respectives nodes...it creates the FCOP_O node label in Neo4j but their nodes don't have properties, those two properties.

Can you please help me?